# Reject A transaction - geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I am developing a certificate verification app, and it has various levels of approval. I want to enable a node to reject a transaction if it does not approve of the certificate. How do I do that?

I am using a geth environment. And I know of options only to mine a transaction (miner.start()) . Not reject it.

Please help!!

Comment: You could modify geth source code that process transactions to reject them. That change is quite low level, so I won't recommend to do it unless you understand how geth works.